# When i run this rake task its giving an error rake aborted........... anu suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive tried with this

rake 'jquery_mobile_rails_css_fix'

but its giving this error

Don't know how to build task 'jquery_mobile_rails_tasks'
/home/vikas/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/final_admin/Rakefile:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3.2/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
/home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3.2/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'

Comment: It'd help to see the task in question.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
rake -T
```

will show you the available tasks.

Since you are using an unix based OS, you can run:

```
rake -T | grep jquery
```

and you will see the jquery related tasks.

Also, you should notice that the simple quotation marks are not required, you should run something like:

```
rake jquery_mobile_rails_tasks
```

Comment: When i checked with rake -T | grep jquery                           it gave me                                                                rake aborted!
Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake -T`